# Disable Gmail app swipe to delete for IMAP account

Tags: email, gmail, google, imap

The Gmail default action swipe to archive make sense for Google accounts.

Now, when I added a normal IMAP account, the swipe action is defaulted to delete, which is dangerous.

Are there any way to enable swipe for archive only, but not delete?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this isn't possible at the moment. The [support article](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6387987?hl=en&rd=1) for Gmail on Android states:

> [You can] set default action & swipe to archive or delete messages for Gmail accounts. For non-Gmail accounts, the default is always delete, so even if you change this setting to archive, your messages will still be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You go into the gmail settings. -> the email account -> and the I think it comes under swipe actions. 
I'm not 100% as I've been using Google inbox but it sounds right...